# Convert Rows to Strings

Tags: r

I have some integer-based survey data. N = 10,000, X = 6. I would like to encode each of the 10,000 observations as a string of 6 variables

Could someone please show me how to encode this in R, such that rows with duplicate strings take on the same assignment?

```
set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(
  matrix(
    sample(1:3,5*12, replace=TRUE),12,5,
    dimnames=list(1:12,c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"))
  ),
  Sex=rep(c("Male", "Female")))
```

Comment: What does "as a string of 6 variables" mean exactly? Can you provide a reproducible example if your expected output?

Comment: Can you clarify “such that rows with duplicate strings take on the same assignment?”

Answer (score 3):

Paste all columns, convert to factor, then convert to integer:

```
dat$id <- as.integer(factor(apply(dat, 1, paste, collapse = "_")))
```

Comment: Thank you @zx8754. Appreciate your help very much :)

Answer (score 3):

We can `paste` columns with a specific `sep`, e.g.,

```
> do.call(paste, c(dat, sep = ", "))
 [1] "1, 1, 1, 2, 2, Male"   "3, 1, 2, 2, 3, Female" "1, 2, 1, 2, 3, Male"
 [4] "2, 2, 1, 3, 2, Female" "1, 2, 2, 2, 2, Male"   "3, 2, 2, 1, 2, Female"
 [7] "3, 3, 2, 3, 2, Male"   "2, 1, 1, 2, 1, Female" "2, 3, 3, 1, 2, Male"
[10] "3, 1, 1, 1, 2, Female" "3, 1, 3, 3, 2, Male"   "1, 1, 2, 2, 2, Female"
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. Again, I appreciate all the different methods for this transformation. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyr::unite()`:

```
library(tidyr)

unite(dat, "X", everything(), sep = " ")
```

```
                  X
1    1 1 1 2 2 Male
2  3 1 2 2 3 Female
3    1 2 1 2 3 Male
4  2 2 1 3 2 Female
5    1 2 2 2 2 Male
6  3 2 2 1 2 Female
7    3 3 2 3 2 Male
8  2 1 1 2 1 Female
9    2 3 3 1 2 Male
10 3 1 1 1 2 Female
11   3 1 3 3 2 Male
12 1 1 2 2 2 Female
```

Comment: I'd use some separator, otherwise there is no difference between "1 12" and "11 2"

Comment: Thanks @zephryl. Appreciate your help a lot. Very useful to see all the perspectives :)

Answer (score 0):

An option with `exec` and `str_c`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   transmute(X= exec(str_c, !!! rlang::syms(names(.)), sep = " "))
```

-output

```
               X
1    1 1 1 2 2 Male
2  3 1 2 2 3 Female
3    1 2 1 2 3 Male
4  2 2 1 3 2 Female
5    1 2 2 2 2 Male
6  3 2 2 1 2 Female
7    3 3 2 3 2 Male
8  2 1 1 2 1 Female
9    2 3 3 1 2 Male
10 3 1 1 1 2 Female
11   3 1 3 3 2 Male
12 1 1 2 2 2 Female
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I appreciate seeing all these different perspectives. Thank you